# Sync data between client and server

Tags: android, ios, mobile, synchronization

I have mobile app. Something like to do list or calendar. Teoretically user can have a few devices with that application on a defferent platforms and so on. I would like to create a automatic synchronization between them through a own server. What is the best practice: update all the information or only the changes? On the one hand usually there is no a lot of data when it's about a to do list but who knows?

Comment: Is it your server or the user's one? You can update all information or only the changes. But which device has all or the latest information? How will you resolve that?

Comment: Ask questions only if you are planning to accept an answer. @thealeksandr

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach is *not* date/time as others suggest, as time can go out of sync. The right algorithm is to keep the checksum of the data entries during last synchronization. On next synchronization you compare current checksums with stored ones, then you know whether the entry has been changed on the server, on the client or both.

Our open-source [Rethync SDK](https://www.eldos.com/rethync/) lets you implement the above approach quite easily and is available for Android (not for iOS at the moment).

Comment: I am sure your open-source SDK handle this. But when there are multiple clients make changes locally and try to sync, how do you know which one is correct? Checksums always differ. If you use timestamp, you can sync only the latest.

Comment: @Raghu No synchronization is concurrent - you always synchronize the server with one client, then with another client. If there were changes on both clients, you should not pick the latest and lose other changes. This is a conflict which you can try to resolve automatically but in most cases one either creates a duplicate entry or asks the user to choose.

Comment: I agree to some extent. But in some use cases (like mine), latest timestamp will do. The reason is my data belongs to a user and if the user chose to update the data from two different devices, he knows that the one he updated latest is the one to be saved. For e.g. user goes to Device 1 edits some content. But the device is offline so no syncing done. Goes to Device 2 and realizes whatever he changed from device 1 is not there. He either makes the changes again or new changes. Device 2 Syncs fine. Back to Device 1 and it tries to sync (because it is online). Here we should ignore it

Comment: @Raghu as a user that does sync from time to time, I never remember that something has been changed in two places, so last time won't work for me (I would lose the changes).

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar in my application. I have a last modified date field with each entity that I need to sync. Then periodically, I post this data to the server (actual data + date and time). Now the server can do one of two things. It will check the corresponding data on server side and compare the last modified date. If what the server is latest, it will return the latest data in response. If not, it will update its data and send a response indicating what client has is latest.

Of course you can do several optimization. That is, mark the data as "dirty" so you know whether to even send your data to server. If the phone does not have modified data, your sync is basically getting the latest data from server.

Basically server does the heavy lifting and does all the logic necessary to maintain the latest data on its end and send responses to client appropriately.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is use a time stamp to handle this.

1. Initial request to server with time stamp value 0.
2. Server will give the  all the data first time with Time-stamp.
3. Store the Time stamp to sharedpreferences.
4. In All next request pass the time stamp back to the server
5. Server will send only those data which are add/update/ after that
   given time stamp
6. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new alternative to the syncing problem. It's called EnduroSync from [Orando Labs](https://orandolabs.com). You can sync object data stores between devices on Android and iOS now, with others coming soon.

Full Disclosure: I work for Orando Labs.

The EnduroSync clients allow you to create object data stores on the local devices. The clients are fairly sophisticated - data is modeled as native objects for each client we support (iOS and Android now, more coming). The clients work offline and online. The data is saved to an sqlite database locally.

As you change objects in your model, the deltas are recorded on the device. At some point, you can 'sync' the object data store. Syncing uses a commit/push/pull process (like git), but this is invisible to you. The sync brings your local copy up to date with whatever is on the server, and sends up any changes you have made. Conflicts are resolved using a timestamp based merge, so newer data is not overwritten by older data.

EnduroSync is an online service, so there is no server setup on your end.

There is also a flexible permission system which lets you share the object data stores in a variety of ways. For instance, most applications will have one or more object data stores for each user, for preferences, notes, tags, etc. You can also share object data stores per app, per user type, and with wild cards, many other ways.

So basically you use our client SDK's to model your data on the device. Modeling is with simple objects in the native programming language of the device. If you sign up for the syncing service, you get the syncing also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

Issue :I need to have the appointments of doctors syned to client (mobile device) from the server. Now the appointments can drop off or the data could possibly change on the server. Having the client to know what change and sending a request back to server could be an expensive service.

Possible approach : Have the server do the heavy lifting. Keep a table which stores values of time stamp and if a change happened with regard to an appointment - cancellation / reschedule etc. The client would then look at this table to see if anything changed. In reality we don't need to sync anything but only the delta which server can provide to the client based on what it has and what is at Client. There is one aspect which needs to be taken care of is updation of info from client to server and traditional conflict management can be done where client can update the server when a data connectivity between client and server exists.

Essentially the approach is to have only the deltas synced by maintaining a checksum or data change log to PUSH changes to the client.